# Update with WHERE IN clause in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to update multiple records in the database with the same value. Is it possible to have `WHERE IN('1','2','3','4','5' ...);` kind of query or maybe `WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 ...`
so that this can happen quickly.

I'm currently trying to update 130 rows with the same value using `saveAll` and it's pretty slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions) ?

```
$this->updateAll(
    array(
       // new values
    ),
    array('id' => array(1,2,3,4,5,6))
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know conditions could be an array of array! Thanks!

Comment: Yes. `array(1,2,3,4,5,6)` generates the `IN (1,2...)`

Comment: "IN" is very slow a chained OR is probably faster. Do a Google search for "mysql in slow" and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that under the hood `updateAll()` runs the following.

```
$statement = $this->query()
    ->update()
    ->set($fields)
    ->where($conditions)
    ->execute();

$statement->closeCursor();

return $statement->rowCount();
```