# Use IN clause in updateAll() method in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am using **Cakephp 3.x** and i want to update my single field for multiple ids. Something like this..

```
UPDATE mytable SET `status` = '1' WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

Currently i am using query to perform this action using cakpehp

```
$this->Leaveregisters->query()
                ->update()
                ->set(['leaveregister_status' => $this->request->data('status')])
                ->where(['leaveregister_id IN ('.$this->request->data('final_ids_string').')'])
                ->execute();
```

Well this does the trick for me but i want this to be performed using cakephp 3.xs' ORM method .. so i am trying to use this instead

```
$table->updateAll(['field' => $newValue], ['id' => $entityId]);
```

But this code is for single id only which i do not want.. i also do not want to use `foeach` loop to perform the same action. Instead i want an **ID** to be passed  via array or comma seperated in any case and want to perform the same action.

Is there any way i can perform the same thing using **ORM** method using **cakephp 3.x**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usinga `updateAll` or a `query()` objects to do a bulk update is the same thing as you can read in the manual at the end of [**this**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates) paragraph

so you can do

```
$this->Leaveregisters->query()
    ->update()
    ->set(['leaveregister_status' => $this->request->data('status')])
    ->where(['leaveregister_id IN' => [1,2,3])
    ->execute();
```

or

```
$this->Leaveregisters->updateAll(
    ['leaveregister_status' => $this->request->data('status')]
    ['leaveregister_id IN' => [1,2,3]);
```

remember then when usin IN clause you have to pass an array. Read [**this**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses) part of the manual on how to create IN clause

Comment: Thank you so much .. this works for me .. Additionaly i was getting values comma seperated and its inside variable so i converted this into an array like this **$int_array = array_map("intval", explode(",", $this->request->data('final_ids_string')));** and then simply sent this array in here **['leaveregister_id IN' => $int_array]** and this did the trick for me .. thank you for your efforts .. highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use array datatype for pass in IN CLAUSE

```
$in_condition= explode(",",$this->request->data('final_ids_string'));

$this->Leaveregisters->query()
                ->update()
                ->set(['leaveregister_status' => $this->request->data('status')])
                ->where(['leaveregister_id IN' => $in_condition])
                ->execute();
```

With updateAll() of Model

```
$table->updateAll(array(
       // new values
    ),
    array('id' => array(1,2,3,4,5,6))
);
```

Comment: i mentioned in my question i have already used this but i want the same thing using updateAll or some other method ..

Comment: Why you what to use with updateAll? there is any problem with update()?

Comment: refere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068164/update-with-where-in-clause-in-cakephp .. its in CakePHP2 but it ill compatible with CakePHP 3 also.

Comment: i have tried both these 2 code **$this->Leaveregisters->updateAll(['leaveregister_status' => $this->request->data('status')], ['id' => array(11,13)]);** and **$this->Leaveregisters->updateAll(
                   array('leaveregister_status' =>$this->request->data('status')),
                    array('id' => array(11,13))
                );**  but i am keep getting this error both the times saying **Cannot convert value to string** what should i do ?